# Swift package build error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create a kitura app, but got stuck at the first steps:

1. Created empty directory
2. `swift package init --type executable`
3. `swift build`

The result: [Build output](https://pastebin.com/EXRJ6cXJ)

I've tried reinstalling command line tools as well as xcode itself with no success..

Thanks in advance!